# Unexpected identifier on Identity.GetUserId

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-identity

I am trying to send the userid from an ajax call to the controller. I need to store it in an object.

The CsHtml page:
http://prntscr.com/bdd644

Which later on results with an error in the rendered html page:
http://prntscr.com/bdd6lv

It gives the: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the code as *text* within the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add apostrophes around:

```
var userId = '@(User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString())';
```

Without them, it will search for variable with the same name as your UserId, which does not exists.
Your projectId works only because it is parsed as number, so that is legal js code.